# I have lost pg_control file in my postgres environment. How can i recreate this file

Tags: postgresql

I have accidently lost my pg_control file. Now I want to recreate this file. Is there a way to create this file again.
Please let me know if there is any command or script available for this purpose.

Incase if I don't have backup of this file can i also copy this file from another instance and paste it on this instance? If yes the what changes i will have to make after copying the file onto the corrupted instance.

The error which i am getting due to lost of this file is as follows:

```
Error: PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
waiting for server to start....postgres: could not find the database system
Expected to find it in the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
but could not open file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/global/pg_control": No such file or directory
stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at [pg_resetwal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgresetwal.html) **READ the entire Description section before doing anything**.